# UIToolbar translucent style and certain UIBarButtonSystemItems

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar

I wanted to post this "question", which I will answer, to help others who may experience this issue. When using a UIToolbar which is translucent, the UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl icon does not appear. Setting barStyle to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent or setting translucent to TRUE causes this. Adding a UIBarButtonItem with a system item of UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl will not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as of 4.2 is to set the UIToolbar's style BEFORE setting its items. Failure to do so will result in a blank button appearing.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I may also point that this issue is still found in 4.3